# Wi-fi issues on a particular computer

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, android

I'm having very severe Wi-fi connectivity issues on one particular computer in my household. Now previously the connection has been very choppy, that is, it has connected and disconnected frequently on it's own accord.

However, after being fed up with this and doing a clean reinstall of W7 on my computer it will no longer connect to my Wi-fi network at all. Now I've tried two different Wi-Fi usb adapters.

I've also tried different sets of drivers and it will not work. Also I've tried to USB-tether through my Android phone, this will work but it will also be choppy, the connection will break randomly and the only way to fix it is to "re-tether" it. Also using my phone as a Wi-fi hotspot won't work either it will connect to the network but it won't get any internet acccess.

Comment: Should we assume that other computers you have work well with the same WIFI hotspot?

Comment: Didn't you physically move your PC at about W7 reinstallation? I mean it could be some kind of interference exactly at you PC location (e.g. i had the same issue when we were using wireless baby camera - it jammed WiFi 1m around it)... Could you test if your phone can connect to the same WiFi (and it works fine) when placed as near your PC as possible? :)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, all other computers and smart devices work just fine with this AP.